# not able to use window builder efficiently with flextable in gwt is it eclipse issue?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, uibinder, windowbuilder

I'm using eclipse indigo and gwt 2.4, when ever i need to use `FlexTable` in my uibinder's xml file i'm just declaring `FlexTable` with some `ui:filed` name and in the counter java file i'm adding the widgets that i need to add to `FlexTable`. but i found the following [link](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/layoutmanagers/gwt/flextable#GraphicalFeedback) that illustrates how to add widgets to `FlexTable` using window builder So what is the issue?

Thanks,

Comment: "Note able to use" => What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: if you look at the link it is showing a scale horizontally and vertically, and when ever you select some widget to put it in some cell it is giving some graphical feedback(like column 1,row 1), but in my case all of the above are not happening i'm just able to add only flex table if i select `FlexTable` and trying to add any widgets it is not allowing (i could see a red colored X mark, not allowing to add widget)